# @oneToOne relationship with Form Wizard IN angular to progress

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am creating one form wizard which have two wizard personal details and bank details now I want to process data and save data dynamically, which I am not getting as I am new to angular.

For backend I have used springboot.

Here is my API - service.ts

```js
 public postData(elite:any){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseurl}/create`,elite)
  }
```

Here is my component html code:

```html
<div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>
          <h1>Form Wizard For Elite</h1>
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="formWizard">
            <form [formGroup]="formWizard">
              <fieldset formGroupName="firstFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your Personal Details</ng-template>
              <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Name">
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>contactNo</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>Courses</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  >
                    <mat-option >
                      option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-form-field example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker" name="date" >
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #datepicker>
                    <mat-datepicker-actions>
                      <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
                      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
                    </mat-datepicker-actions>
                  </mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  >
                    <mat-option >
                      option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>City</mat-label>
                  <mat-select >
                    <mat-option >
                     option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-label><h3>Select an option for payment</h3></mat-label>
                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" >
                  <mat-radio-button value="online">Online</mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button value="cash" >Cash</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
              </div>
               <div class="md-3">
               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Leave a description</mat-label>
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..." ></textarea>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="md-3">
              <mat-checkbox >Approved</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
              <div>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mt20" matStepperNext >Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="formWizard">
            <form [formGroup]="formWizard">
              <fieldset formGroupName="secondFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your Bank Information</ng-template>
              <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Account No</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Name">
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Owner Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>IFSC Code</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
              <div>
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="ml20" matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Preview</ng-template>
            <form [formGroup]="formWizard">
              <fieldset formGroupName="thirdFormGroup"></fieldset>
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your Personal Details</ng-template>
              <h2 class="mt20"><b>Personal Infromation</b></h2>
              <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Name">
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>contactNo</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>Courses</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  >
                    <mat-option >
                      option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-form-field example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker" name="date" >
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #datepicker>
                    <mat-datepicker-actions>
                      <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
                      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
                    </mat-datepicker-actions>
                  </mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
                  <mat-select  >
                    <mat-option >
                      option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width mt20 width">
                  <mat-label>City</mat-label>
                  <mat-select >
                    <mat-option >
                     option1
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-label><h3>Select an option for payment</h3></mat-label>
                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" >
                  <mat-radio-button value="online">Online</mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button value="cash" >Cash</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
              </div>
               <div class="md-3">
               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Leave a description</mat-label>
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..." ></textarea>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="md-3">
              <mat-checkbox >Approved</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <h2 class="mt20"><b>Bank Infromation</b></h2>
              <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Account No</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Name">
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>Owner Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
               <div class="md-3">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-label>IFSC Code</mat-label>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contactNo" >
                </mat-form-field>
               </div>
            </form>

            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="ml20" matStepperNext (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </mat-step>
        </mat-stepper>
      </mat-card-header>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript code:

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { EliteService } from '../elite.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-wizard',
  templateUrl: './form-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-wizard.component.css']
})
export class FormWizardComponent {

  formWizard !:  FormGroup;
   
  public elite = {
    name : '',
    contactNo : '',
    approval: '',
    description : '',
    paymentMode : '',
    date : '',
    state : {
      id: ''
    },
    city : {
      id: ''
    },
    course : {
     id : ''
    },
    bankDetails : {
      id : '',
      accountNo : '',
      owner : '',
      ifsc  : ''
    }
}

public city = [
  {
    id : '',
    city : ''
  }
]


 public state = [
  {
    id : '',
    state : ''
  }
]

public courses = [
 {
     id : '',
     courseName : ''
 }
] 

public bankDetails = [
  {
    id : '',
    accountNo : '',
    owner : '',
    ifsc  : ''
  }
]


constructor( @Inject(FormBuilder) _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.formWizard = _formBuilder.group({
    firstFormGroup: _formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          contactNo: ['', Validators.required],
          course: ['', Validators.required],
          city: ['', Validators.required],
          state: ['', Validators.required],
          approval: ['', Validators.required],
          description: ['', Validators.required],
          paymentMode: ['', Validators.required],
          date: ['', Validators.required],

      }),
      secondFormGroup: _formBuilder.group({
          accountNo: ['', Validators.required],
          owner: ['', Validators.required],
          ifsc: ['', Validators.required],
      }),
      thirdFormGroup: _formBuilder.group({
        //preview of all this
        name: ['', Validators.required],
          contactNo: ['', Validators.required],
          course: ['', Validators.required],
          city: ['', Validators.required],
          state: ['', Validators.required],
          approval: ['', Validators.required],
          description: ['', Validators.required],
          paymentMode: ['', Validators.required],
          date: ['', Validators.required],
          accountNo: ['', Validators.required],
          owner: ['', Validators.required],
          ifsc: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  });
}

}
```

Above share code I tried I want dynamic data in it.